# Fail to compile NancyFX

Tags: raspbian, software-compilation, mono

I'm trying to compile NancyFx on my raspberry using this [guide](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Running-Nancy-on-your-Raspberry-Pi) but fail at step 5.

The command "rake mono" failes with the error

> uninitialized constant Albacore:Task

So, I guess there is something wrong with my albacore installation. I've tried the install of albacore with the first command:

> sudo gem install albacore

Which goes fine, also tried:

> sudo gem install albacore --pre

Also goes fine, but does not solve the rake problem.

Also tried the workaround mentioned in the guide, by installing rubyzip 0.9.9.. installs fine but Nancy won't compile..

Now i'm out of options.

Answer (score 1):

I had to go to 1.0.rc.2 to get it compiling.  Also, I did a `sudo su -` before running instead of as pi.  So

```
gem uninstall albacore
gem install albacore --version "~> 1.0.rc"
```

then `rake mono`

Comment: I just had the same error after installing Albacore v2.0.6. I may have to revert to something older.